How to change breadcrumbs of WebView opened as a CustomEditor in VSCode?
I am developing a VSCode extension with a CustomEditor for editing HTML.
When I open the WebView of the CustomEditor, breadcrumbs containing only the file name are displayed at the top, as shown in the image below.

I would like to change the content displayed in these breadcrumbs.
How can I do this?
